# Any filter is a neighborhood filter with a fixed point removed from all neighborhoods. Is the topology which produces this neighborhood unique?

Tags: general-topology, filters

Assume $\mathcal F$ is a filter on the set $X$ and $\infty \notin X$ and
$$Y=X\cup \{\infty\}$$
We know there's some topology $\mathcal T$ on $Y$ such that
$$\mathcal F =\{U\cap X \mid U \text{ is a neighborhood of } \infty \text{ in } (Y,\mathcal T) \} $$

Is this topology unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X=\{x\}$, where the filter is $\{\{x\}\}$, there are two topologies on $Y=\{x,\infty\}$. The indiscrete one and the Sierpiński topology $\{\emptyset,\{x\},Y\}$.